# How to make Discord Bot skip deleting message if they contain *DD

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
 var input = message.content.toUpperCase();
  if(input.indexOf("*DD") != -1) {
    if (J===null) {
        setTimeout(function() {
              bot.deleteMessage(message);
         }, 1000);
      }
   }
});
```

This creates no errors when starting the bot, but does not delete any messages. If *DD is entered the bot puts out the error "J is not defined"
Any help would be great

Answer (score 1):

I've never worked with the Discord-API. But if this is just plain JavaScript, the error is probably at your *indexOf* function:

```
if (input.indexOf("DD") != -1) {
...
}
```

Also see here: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp

Your complete code would be:

```
bot.on("message", function(message) {
    if(input.indexOf("DD") != -1) {
        if (J===null) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                  bot.deleteMessage(message);
            }, 120000);
        }
     }
});
```

Comment: this worked to the point of it runs the bot I'm going to update my code

Comment: Maybe the timeout is too long? I added 5 zeros instead of 4 :P

Comment: No problem. Is it the Discord-Api to throw an error?

Comment: I think, it tells me in the command window it starts in. The bot starts which means the code identifies J===null

Comment: Do you have an error message? Also, I looked up the discord api, and there is states that the deleteMessage function needs more arguments. Maybe thats a problem too..